# Search then replace it with last 4 characters

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have here a csv file with the following data

```
1,2,CC-12345678-20201120,6
1,3,CC-87654321-20201110,5
```

I need to replace the specific string after “CC-“ with its 4 last digit

Expected output:

```
1,2,CC-5678-20201120,6
1,3,CC-4321-20201110,5
```

Im trying to use awk or sed. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`

```
sed 's/CC-[^-]*\([^-]\{4\}\)/CC-\1/' file
```

or more readable with extended regular expressions:

```
sed -E 's/CC-[^-]*([^-]{4})/CC-\1/' file
```

This `s`ubstitutes the `CC-` and any following number of non-dashes `[^-]*` by the last four non-dashes `[^-]\{4\}` by `CC-` followed by the four chars we marked with `\(\)`.

Comment: I like your approach. Though using a simplified (since it only concers the 4 chars after first `-`) it could get as `sed 's/CC-...[^-]/CC-/' file`

Comment: I've learned not to trust given examples. You are right: In the example file there is always eight digits after the `CC-`, so you can simplify, but as OP doesn't say to *remove the first four digits*, it could also be `CC-foo1111` and wants to keep `CC-1111`. Who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\([^-]*-\)[0-9]\+\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1\2/' input_file
1,2,CC-5678-20201120,6

1,3,CC-4321-20201110,5
```

Comment: This will only keep the last four digits if the string after `CC-` is always 8 chars.

Comment: @Philippos Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

with `awk` :

```
awk -F- -v OFS=- '$1~/,CC$/{$2=substr($2, length($2)-3)}1' file
```

Split the string by `-`, then if the first field end with the desired pattern (`,CC`) get the last 4 character. Print all the line (`1`).